# Can I make a good pizza in a home portable oven?

Tags: oven, pizza, slow-cooking

I have a portable small oven with a max temperature of 250°C.

There are two hot bars, one at the top and the other at the bottom.

First of all, I'm not sure that I can get good pizza in that.

My crust never gets heated much, it looks like the base is not heated when it's on the plate.

So I want to ask if it's possible to get a good pizza at 250°C.

Comment: Could you possibly show us a picture of the oven? Dimensions could be helpful too. I'm thinking a pizza stone could help you a lot, but I can't imagine your oven. 250C is not much below the max temp of many full sized ovens.

Comment: @Jolenealaska I *think* OP is describing what I'd call a toaster oven. Those most of those have more than two elements.

Comment: What kind or style of pizza do you perceive is good? I don't know that I've ever made a pizza that cooks at 250° C. and I really liked a lot of the pizza we've made. What kind of crust do you have? How much sauce? Do you cook it on the rack or another surface? How many toppings? Do you like brick oven types?

Comment: Sure, you can make it in there, it tends to be a bit of a cramped environment though. Now for baking, though, that oven might be the wrong choice.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you call "good".

On the one end of the scale, you have people who don't go to pizzerias with an electric or gas commercial oven and insist on wooden fired ovens which get the pizza ready in 90 seconds. On the other end, there are people who will be happy with anything flat with a covering of tomato sauce hot enough to sear the roof of the mouth. Without knowing where you fall on the scale, I don't know if pizzas from this oven will reach your threshold of "good".

But I will encourage you to make pizza in it. I have been using nothing but a toaster oven myself for the last 10 years, and it works well for me for all the usual purposes. It is better for pizza than the usual big home ovens, because its higher ratio of radiation vs convection heating is more similar to a fire oven than that of the usual electric home ovens. (Not everything is rosy though - this same quality makes it inferior for cakes and oven roasts).

So, go ahead and make your pizza.

Answer (score 2):

There are a large variety of pizza types and styles, with different doughs, crusts, and toppings.

While it is difficult to make a VPN napolotana style pizza without a wood fired oven, there are a myriad other types of pizza.

Many of these in fact work quite well in home style ovens, and even toaster or portable ovens.

See the Food Lab's article on [Three Doughs To Know](http://slice.seriouseats.com/archives/2012/07/the-pizza-lab-three-doughs-to-know.html), which describes three different types of pizza dough (from the many).  The Sicilian style pizza works extremely well in a toaster oven.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can just as easily change the type of crust (eg, my mom made english muffin pizzas in a toaster oven growing up, and I still do the same with naan or other flatbreads), if you're set on making your own crust, I'd recommend par-baking the crust before adding toppings.

Place the crust in the oven, and give it a chance to bake until it's gotten a chance to crust up a bit.  Then pull it, (possibly flip it, depending on how even the baking it in your oven), add your toppings, and return it to the oven to heat the toppings and melt the cheese.

Comment: Joe, I think you are assuming a specific type of crust here, like a new york style or a napolitan style... might want to make that clear.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ : My only assumption is that there's a crust that's not cooking completely with the current methods being used, and that they want that type of crust.  Therefore, pre-baking, the same that you'd do if you have an under-powered full size oven.

Answer (score 1):

I use the type of oven pictured here http://www.sunflame.com/oven_toster_griller_large.php?id=3 to bake pizza. I turn the heat all the way up with both heating coils turned on, I invert the cookie sheet (tray) and put it on the top shelf. After it heats up, I wait for the thermostat light to turn back on, and then I slide my pizza in on top of it from a wooden board. It bakes in less than five minutes, and makes decent pizza.

You don't need to par-cook your crust for this.

Answer (score 0):

Get toaster oven heated to 425F. Then roll dough (after rise), then cut carefully with sharp knife (to fit pan size). Coat toaster oven pan lightly with oil. Fit dough in pan. Put in toaster oven.

Look through glass occasionally for browning on top, then when browning just starts, take out and turn over. Put back in for a few minutes then take out again. If it feels or looks at least half cooked put sauce down, sprinkle oregano on it and toppings. Put back in oven for about 12 minutes or till cheese melts.

Note: I can't judge cooking raw sausage or any other meats less they're cooked first! Use trial and error. Experiment with different combos.

Note 2: This is with store made dough.

Comment: A few rules here - we don't talk bad about other posters (if you disagree, you can downvote once you have enough rep points), posts with "note: I didn't try this" with comparatvely simple things don't inspire trust in me and finally, spellchecking and a few blanks greatly improve readability. I recommend you take the [tour], visit our [help] and consider [edit] your post a bit.